# How to obtain results divided by region with R package `gtrendsR`

Tags: r

If I type a word on Google Trends https://trends.google.it/, I get the results divided by region (Latium, Tuscany, etc.) or by city.

I tried to obatin the same results resorting to the R package `gtrendsR`:

```
library(gtrendsR)
x<-gtrends("ciao", time = "now 1-H") # last hour
```

and I obtained

```
str(x)
List of 7
 $ interest_over_time :'data.frame':    56 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ date    : POSIXct[1:56], format: "2023-04-21 06:22:00" "2023-04-21 06:23:00" "2023-04-21 06:24:00" ...
  ..$ hits    : int [1:56] 43 98 73 66 44 79 60 52 66 42 ...
  ..$ keyword : chr [1:56] "ciao" "ciao" "ciao" "ciao" ...
  ..$ geo     : chr [1:56] "world" "world" "world" "world" ...
  ..$ time    : chr [1:56] "now 1-H" "now 1-H" "now 1-H" "now 1-H" ...
  ..$ gprop   : chr [1:56] "web" "web" "web" "web" ...
  ..$ category: int [1:56] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ interest_by_country:'data.frame':    250 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ location: chr [1:250] "Belize" "New Caledonia" "Sierra Leone" "Jersey" ...
  ..$ hits    : chr [1:250] "" "" "100" "" ...
  ..$ keyword : chr [1:250] "ciao" "ciao" "ciao" "ciao" ...
  ..$ geo     : chr [1:250] "world" "world" "world" "world" ...
  ..$ gprop   : chr [1:250] "web" "web" "web" "web" ...
 $ interest_by_region : NULL
 $ interest_by_dma    :'data.frame':    306 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ location: chr [1:306] "Terre Haute IN" "Albany GA" "Rochester MN-Mason City IA-Austin MN" "Odessa-Midland TX" ...
  ..$ hits    : chr [1:306] "100" "72" "40" "36" ...
  ..$ keyword : chr [1:306] "ciao" "ciao" "ciao" "ciao" ...
  ..$ geo     : chr [1:306] "world" "world" "world" "world" ...
  ..$ gprop   : chr [1:306] "web" "web" "web" "web" ...
 $ interest_by_city   :'data.frame':    200 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ location: chr [1:200] "Talmassons" "Tribano" "Valle Lomellina" "Ronco All'Adige" ...
  ..$ hits    : int [1:200] NA NA NA NA NA NA 100 NA NA NA ...
  ..$ keyword : chr [1:200] "ciao" "ciao" "ciao" "ciao" ...
  ..$ geo     : chr [1:200] "world" "world" "world" "world" ...
  ..$ gprop   : chr [1:200] "web" "web" "web" "web" ...
 $ related_topics     :'data.frame':    34 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ subject       : chr [1:34] "100" "82" "21" "17" ...
  ..$ related_topics: chr [1:34] "top" "top" "top" "top" ...
  ..$ value         : chr [1:34] "Ciao" "Bella ciao" "Piaggio Ciao" "Italian" ...
  ..$ keyword       : chr [1:34] "ciao" "ciao" "ciao" "ciao" ...
  ..$ category      : int [1:34] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "reshapeLong")=List of 4
  .. ..$ varying:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ value: chr "top"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "v.names")= chr "value"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "times")= chr "top"
  .. ..$ v.names: chr "value"
  .. ..$ idvar  : chr "id"
  .. ..$ timevar: chr "related_topics"
 $ related_queries    :'data.frame':    21 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ subject        : chr [1:21] "100" "21" "8" "8" ...
  ..$ related_queries: chr [1:21] "top" "top" "top" "top" ...
  ..$ value          : chr [1:21] "bella ciao" "ciao meaning" "ciao in inglese" "ciao bella meaning" ...
  ..$ keyword        : chr [1:21] "ciao" "ciao" "ciao" "ciao" ...
  ..$ category       : int [1:21] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "reshapeLong")=List of 4
  .. ..$ varying:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ value: chr "top"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "v.names")= chr "value"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "times")= chr "top"
  .. ..$ v.names: chr "value"
  .. ..$ idvar  : chr "id"
  .. ..$ timevar: chr "related_queries"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gtrends" "list"
```

(I can't share the result obtained with `dput` because it is too long)

For example in the `interest_by_city` field I read many cities but no regions. Reading the manual of `gtrendsR` I didn't find any suggestion for fixing this problem.

Comment: If you don't specify any geographic area, it uses the countries and doesn't use regions because there would be too many. If you want to see the regions, you need to specify a country, with `geo = "IT"` for example

Comment: It was easier than expected. Thank you!